# Is there any way to check the google map with insecure origin during development phase?

Tags: google-maps

console error is

> getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure
>   origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your
>   application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look here in order to improve your questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: no, you cannot use those two methods in the API with insecure origins, because they reveal potentially personally identifiable information. It says so right in the error message.

You can get around this by either using a dev box with a certificate for development, or if you need to iterate quickly locally, consider issuing and whitelisting a self-signed cert, then setting your local machine as a trusted origin.